# How to decrese indent of a selection in xml in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have pasted some xml into an xml file in vscode.
The selection is indented to much. I would like to move the block to the left.
In Eclipse this is done using Source / Shift Left. 
Is there an equivalent for this in vscode?

I found the shortcut to format Shift Option F but it does not do anything in my selection and I do not want to reformat the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `LeftShift + Tabulation` it does the work for me.